# What state should wrapped ByteBuffers be returned in?

Tags: java, io, nio, bytebuffer

I'm having trouble groking the practical aspects of Java NIO's Buffers.

NIO offers a series of typed Buffers that present a data oriented view over a ByteBuffer (i.e. CharBuffer, IntBuffer, DoubleBuffer, etc).

When returning one of these typed buffer views from a backing buffer, what is the preferable state (or what would appear as the least surprising state to a caller) for the returned buffer to be in? E.g.:

```
class Data<T> {
    ByteBuffer buffer;

    abstract T getData()
}

class CharData extends Data<CharBuffer> {

    CharBuffer getData() {
        CharBuffer charBuffer = buffer.asCharBuffer();
        // Should I adjust something here before returning?
        return charBuffer;
    }
}
```

Should it be set to "write mode"? I.e. leave position as is, set limit to capacity?

Should it be set to "read mode"? I.e. leave limit as is, set position to 0?

Should it be presented as "full"? I.e. set limit to capacity, position to 0?

What is the best approach if in addition, I can assume that the buffer will always be full, but want to facilitate random access to the contents?

I'm sure that this is a trivial question for more seasoned IO programmers, but after bumping into a few weird gotchas working with buffers, I decided to come here and ask what people think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always return it ready for reading (and I always keep them that way internally, except for very short flip/write/compact or flip/get/compact sequences that are clearly visible in the code: and I always do the compact in a finally block).

I don't see a reason to present it as full, but if you're putting data into it before returning you could consider returning it already flipped, like `ByteBuffer.wrap()` does. But I don't really agree with this practice. If you do that, make sure you document it.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the last bit? The reason I see to return them as full, is that both ByteBuffer.allocate() and ByteBuffer.wrap() behave like that, so it's kinda consistent with the way in which buffers are generally obtained... This does tend to imply that the buffer is "empty", but I intend to read and write full buffers on every access, so it seems reasonable to me... Does this mean that I might be better off using something other than ByteBuffers?

Comment: `allocate()` returns the buffer as empty. `wrap()` returns it as flipped. Neither returns it as full, and neither should you, unless it *is* full. You can't read into a full buffer, and you don't need a full buffer to be able to write from it.